# How to plot surface with constraints using ezsurf in MATLAB R2014b?

Tags: matlab, plot, surface

I want to plot the surface of function `f=((x1+1.5)^2+5*(x2-1.7)^2)*((x1-1.4)^2+0.6*(x2-0.5)^2);`
with constraints:

```
-x1<0
-x2<0
3*x1-x1*x2+4*x2-7<0
2*x1+x2-3<0
3*x1-4*x2^2-4*x2<0
```

in MATLAB R2014b.

I only can plot `f` using `ezsurf` but I don't know to define the constraints. How to plot `f` with constraints?

```
syms x1 x2;
f=((x1+1.5)^2+5*(x2-1.7)^2)*((x1-1.4)^2+0.6*(x2-0.5)^2);
ezsurf(f);
hold on;
```

ADDENDUM:
As @Ander Biguri's comment, I have tried make the code as follows:

```
x=0:0.1:2;
y=0:0.1:2;
[X1,X2]=meshgrid(x,y);
constraint1 = -X1<=0;
constraint2 = -X2<=0;
constraint3 = 3*X1-X1*X2+4*X2-7<=0;
constraint4 = 2*X1+X2-3<=0;
constraint5 = 3*X1-4*X2^2-4*X2<=0;
X1(~constraint1) = NaN;
X2(~constraint1) = NaN;
X1(~constraint2) = NaN;
X2(~constraint2) = NaN;
X1(~constraint3) = NaN;
X2(~constraint3) = NaN;
X1(~constraint4) = NaN;
X2(~constraint4) = NaN;
X1(~constraint5) = NaN;
X2(~constraint5) = NaN;
f=((X1+1.5).^2+5*(X2-1.7).^2)*((X1-1.4).^2+0.6*(X2-0.5).^2);
surf(X1,X2,f);
```

But nothing appear in the figure.

[image]

What is my mistake?

Comment: An alternative is for you to do this numerically. Give values of `x1` and `x2` that fit your constrains, then evaluate `f` and use `surf`. Is there any reason you want to do this symbolically?

Comment: I use `ezsurf` just for easiness.

Comment: Seems that you reach the point where its not easier though! Try to do this numerically. You just need `meshgrid` to create values of `x1` and `x2`, then apply the conditions to eliminate non-valid `x1` `x2` (e.g. make them NaN) and then use `surf`

Comment: @Ander Biguri 
I have tried to make the code as your suggestion. But nothing plot is appear (see my edited question). What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your second version (numerical) is a typical one: use elementwise operations instead of matrix operations:

```
f=((X1+1.5).^2+5*(X2-1.7).^2).*((X1-1.4).^2+0.6*(X2-0.5).^2);
```

[image]

Comment: In the constraint, we must use elementwise operation so `constraint3` should be
`constraint3 = 3*X1-X1.*X2+4*X2-7<=0;` and `constraint5` should be `constraint5 = 3*X1-4*X2.^2-4*X2<=0;`

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, there too @OngkyDennyWijaya